# "Login" into MySQL Database via Objective-C with POST - Request

Tags: php, mysql, objective-c

I have a MySQL database with a user-table. It contains the ids and email-addresses of users.

In Objective-C I want to send a user's email-address via POST to a php-File which compare it with the email-address stored in database. If they match, the user is "logged in",  otherwise he/she is asked to do.

Unfortunately my way to solve that doesn't work. I assume the POST variable isn't set. Cause when I enter the email-address directly in the php file it works.

Here is my code:

Objective-C:

```
-(void)login{
   NSString *email = @"test@test.test";

   NSString *rawStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"email=%@",email];

   NSData *data = [rawStr dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

   NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://localhost/test/login.php"];
   NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

   [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   [request setHTTPBody:data];

   NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
   NSURLSessionUploadTask *uploadTask = [session uploadTaskWithRequest:request
                                            fromData:data
                                            completionHandler:
                                            ^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error){
                                                if (data == nil) {
                                                    NSLog(@"Failure");
                                                }
                                                else{
                                                    NSLog(@"Successful");
                                                }
                                          }];

   [uploadTask resume];
}
```

PHP: login.php

```
<?php 
   session_start();

   $db_host = 'localhost';
   $db_name = 'test';
   $db_user = 'root';
   $db_password = '';

   $pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=$db_host;dbname=$db_name", $db_user, $db_password);

   $email = trim($_POST['email']); //"test@test.test";

   $statement = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE email = :email");
   $result = $statement->execute(array('email' => $email));
   $user = $statement->fetch();

   //Login
   $_SESSION['userid'] = $user['id'];

   if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {
       die("You have to login!");
   }
   else{
       echo "You are logged in!";
   }
?>
```

PS: Excuse my bad englisch, it´s not my native Language.

Update:

For example, if i run the internal.php after running login.php (email-address directly inserted in login.php), "Hello" is output. When I try to do that via Xcode, "You have to login!", is output.

PHP: internal.php

```
<?php 
   session_start();
   require_once("inc/config.inc.php");

   if(!isset($_SESSION['userid'])) {        
      die("You have to login!");
   }
   else{
      echo "Hello!";
}
```

?>

Comment: Does the user only need to have an email adress to log in to your system? I mean without passwords?

Comment: I will add it later, when I´ve understood whats wrong.

Comment: The words "doesn't work" are not helpful. Please provide more details. Do you get any errors? Specify in what way exactly it doesn't work.

Comment: @rmaddy Thank you for your note. I have updated my question.